# Fetch sftp error values in expect shell

Tags: shell, expect

I was trying to do a sftp using expect shell. But I was not able to fetch the different sftp error codes that could possibly occur. Instead I was getting the return value as 0

Here is the code snippet and op

```
"${sftp_prompt}" {

send "${command}\r"
    expect "${sftp_prompt}"

    # Close the sftp session
    send "bye\r"

expect eof

set details [wait]

puts "sftp exit status=[lindex $details 3]"

   }

}
```

Output:

```
spawn sftp root@dsc-A

Connecting to dsc-A...

root@dsc-a's password:

sftp> get shiv.txt /var/log/nsn/pkiclient/Response_files/

Couldn't stat remote file: No such file or directory

File "/root/shiv.txt" not found.

sftp> bye

sftp exit status=0

SSH_ERROR_OK | Indicates successful completion of the operation
```

Desired op : I am expecting the exit status to be 10, which corresponds to

> sftp error - SSH_ERROR_NO_SUCH_PATH | The file path does not exist or
>   is invalid.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Your sftp session exits normally that's why you are getting a result code of 0.
You need to trap for sftp errors in your expect block.

```
set timeout 60
send "$command\r"
expect {
    timeout {
        puts "A timeout occured"
        exit 1 
    }

    #One of many errors 
    -re "Couldn't|Can't" {
        puts "Can not perform $command"
        exit 2 
    } 

    #Ok 
    "sftp>" {
        puts "$command completed successfully"
    }
}
```